# Watson Conversation node.js create workspace with learning_opt_out

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to create a new watson-conversation workspace with `learning_opt_out true` in node.js.
The following code creates the workspace, but `learning_opt_out` is still `false`.

Can you help?

```
var watson = require("watson-developer-cloud");

var conversation = new watson.ConversationV1({
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  url: 'https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/',
  version_date: '2017-05-26'
});

var workspace = {
  name: 'API test',
  description: 'Example workspace created via API.',
  language: 'de',
  learning_opt_out: 'true'
};

conversation.createWorkspace(workspace, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  }
 });
```

Running this code creates the following output:

```
{
  "name": "API test",
  "created": "2017-10-27T12:16:11.170Z",
  "updated": "2017-10-27T12:16:11.170Z",
  "language": "de",
  "metadata": null,
  "description": "Example workspace created via API.",
  "workspace_id": "xxx",
  "learning_opt_out": false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [you can see](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1#!/Workspaces/createWorkspace), the parameter for `learning_opt_out` is **boolean**:

> learning_opt_out (boolean, optional): Whether training data from the
>   workspace can be used by IBM for general service improvements. true
>   indicates that workspace training data is not to be used.

**EDIT:**

After saw more about this question and the parameter learning_opt_out, I [found](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-logging.html#controlling-request-logging-for-watson-services) the answer, you need to set one `header` inside your call for Conversation service and your `username` and `password`:

For example:

```
var watson = require("watson-developer-cloud");

var conversation = new watson.ConversationV1({
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  url: 'https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/',
  version_date: '2017-05-26',
  //X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT: true
  headers: {
       'X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out': true
  }
});

var workspace = {
  name: 'API test',
  description: 'Example workspace created via API.',
  language: 'de',
  //'X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT': true
};

conversation.createWorkspace(workspace, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  }
});
```

And the result:

```
{
  "name": "API test",
  "created": "2017-11-03T12:16:08.025Z",
  "updated": "2017-11-03T12:16:08.025Z",
  "language": "de",
  "metadata": null,
  "description": "Example workspace created via API.",
  "workspace_id": "c143cfd2-2350-491e-bc58-b9debf06e03f",
  "learning_opt_out": true
}
```

- See more about [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object.
- Watson API Explorer examples for [Watson Conversation](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1).

Comment: Hello - I now changed it to "learning_opt_out: true" .. the response still is:
{
  "name": "API test",
  "created": "2017-11-03T11:17:47.730Z",
  "updated": "2017-11-03T11:17:47.730Z",
  "language": "de",
  "metadata": null,
  "description": "Example workspace created via API.",
  "workspace_id": "xxxxxx",
  "learning_opt_out": false
}

Comment: So, I [found](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-logging.html#controlling-request-logging-for-watson-services) the problem, try to see my edit please